# Jenkins | Use method from an imported java class in a groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to use a method from a Jenkins plugin via its java class

Just to point out I'm not a developer or a groovy/java expert - happy to learn!

The java class that my method is part of is `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator`

From this I would like to use the method `getRepoOwner()`

What I've done is set my import and defined a new call to the class:

```
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator

def bbSCMNav = new BitbucketSCMNavigator()
```

When I run this I get the error below:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
  public com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator#<init>(java.lang.String)
  public com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator#<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

I've searched for the error above `Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list`

And I came across this ticket [Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list on newInstance in groovy closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346233/could-not-find-which-method-init-to-invoke-from-this-list-on-newinstance-in)

Can't say that I entirerly understand the reply if it's helpful to me or not as I say I'm not a developer and groovy and java are relatively new to me but happy to understand if anyone can point me in the right direction with this

The goal of this exercise is to use the method during the run-time of a build to get the output of `getRepoOwner()` and use that in a variable to construct a URI

This question also seems similar to mine - [Calling internal methods of Jenkins plugin (thinBackup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289797/calling-internal-methods-of-jenkins-plugin-thinbackup)

But I'm not using maven or a pom.xml here

Cheers

Comment: The error message implies the constructor requires arguments of either one or three strings. You should probably look up the documentation on the class usage.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think you're right here as the constructor has the following(if I'm looking at the right place), here it's looking for a string type of repoOwner:

`@DataBoundConstructor
    public BitbucketSCMNavigator(String repoOwner) {
        this.serverUrl = BitbucketCloudEndpoint.SERVER_URL;
        this.repoOwner = repoOwner;
        this.traits = new ArrayList<>();
        this.credentialsId = null; // highlighting the default is anonymous unless you configure explicitly
    }`

Comment: It seems that the 3 string constructor is deprecated
`@Deprecated // retained for binary compatibility
    public BitbucketSCMNavigator(String repoOwner, String credentialsId, String checkoutCredentialsId)`

And I think my question is the altered considerably as I don't think I'm looking at the right class as I want to return the *owner* NOT use it as an agrument to a function. So as it stands my question is still valid from the point-of-view that I want to call a method to return the owner but it from another class that provides it!

Answer (score 0):

## Quick Answer

This error **Could not find which method < init >()** is related to a missing constructor.

Almost all internal jenkins class are ready to use in groovy.

In your case, BitbucketSCMNavigator does not have a default constructor. It have a constructor with one String argument.  Check this [line](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/e5f605ba1ec0524ac5cad7b29290acfd489e0ee9/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/bitbucket/BitbucketSCMNavigator.java#L576)

## Explanation

I could replicate your error with another internal class  **org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory**:

```
node {

   stage('internal') {
      org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory obj = 
      new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory();
   }

}
```

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
      private org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory#<init>(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List)`

But, reviewing this class [CpsFlowExecution](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecution.java) I could see that CpsGroovyShellFactory does not have a default constructor. It have a constructor with one argument : CpsGroovyShellFactory(this)

So, If I instance the constructor with one argument, no errors appear.

```
node {

   stage('internal') {
      org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory obj = 
      new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShellFactory(null);
   }

}
```